# visual studio extension keyprocessor , suppress enter key's default behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyevent, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins

I'm develop a Visual Studio Extension which try to suppress Enter/Return key's default behavior (change caret to next line). So I can do some custom operation such as move caret to the end when press enter before close brace (like Eclipse)

```
[Export(typeof(IKeyProcessorProvider))]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument)]
[ContentType("any")]
[Name("ToTheEndKeyProvider")]
[Order(Before="default")]
internal class ToTheEndKeyProvider : IKeyProcessorProvider
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ToTheEndKeyProvider()
    {

    }

    public KeyProcessor GetAssociatedProcessor(IWpfTextView wpfTextView)
    {
        if (wpfTextView == null)
            return null;
        return new ToTheEndKeyProcessor(wpfTextView,wpfTextView.TextBuffer) as KeyProcessor;
    } 
}

class ToTheEndKeyProcessor : KeyProcessor
{
    IWpfTextView view { get; set; }
    ITextBuffer buffer { get; set; }

    public ToTheEndKeyProcessor(IWpfTextView wpfTextView,ITextBuffer textBuffer)
    {
        this.view = wpfTextView;
        this.buffer = textBuffer;
    }

    public override void PreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {                            
        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
        {
             e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the issue:

- when override PreviewKeyDown/KeyDown, enter key not fire , other key can do
- when override PreviewKeyUp/KeyUp, enter key fired, but e.Handled = true can't suppress the default behavior

I also tried PreviewTextInput, but it seems can get '\r' char.
Is there any solution which can handler vs editor's key event without KeyProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same question.

I have not found the way to handle Enter/Return key input with KeyProcessor, but by implementing IOleCommandTarget, I could handle it.
Please refer to following article:

http://www.alashiban.com/multi-editing-tutorial/

Comment: While this link may answer the question or provide a workaround, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.